# How do I combine "itemize", "tabto" and "align" properly?

Tags: align, matrices, itemize, tabto

I am new to LaTeX and I'd like to put a matrix into an itemize environment.

I achieved it with this (more or less):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabto} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[a)]   Item 1\\
                Example: \tabto{6cm} TestTestTest
    \item[b)]   Item 2\\
                Example: \vspace{-23pt} %to get the array into the same line
                \begin{align*}\begin{array}{ccc}
                    \hspace{3.8cm}(1;1); &\ldots; &(1;6);\\
                    \hspace{3.8cm}(2;1); &\ldots; &(2;6);\\
                \end{array}\end{align*}
\end{itemize}       
\end{document}
```

But I just can't figure out how to avoid guessing the parameters of `\vspace` and `\hspace` until it kind of looks right.

I hope somebody knows what I could do better.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

Se if the following solutione gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[a)]   Item 1\\
                Example: \tabto{6cm} Test Test Test
    \item[b)]   Item 2\\
                Example: \tabto{5.5cm} $\begin{array}[t]{ccc}
                                        (1;1); &\ldots; &(1;6);\\
                                        (2;1); &\ldots; &(2;6);
                                      \end{array}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]